# SBT - bad revision found

Tags: maven, dependencies, sbt

I get an error:

> expected='**2.0.0-SNAPSHOT** found='**${jpacontainer.version}**'

```
Vaadin snapshot repository: bad revision found in
http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/com/vaadin/addon/jpacontainer-addon-agpl-3.0/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/jpacontainer-addon-agpl-3.0-2.0.0-20120117.082939-16.pom:
expected='2.0.0-SNAPSHOT found='${jpacontainer.version}'
```

while resolving dependency

```
val vaadinJPA = "com.vaadin.addon" % "jpacontainer-addon-agpl-3.0" % "2.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

Do you know how to fix this?

This is the POM: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/com/vaadin/addon/jpacontainer-addon-agpl-3.0/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/jpacontainer-addon-agpl-3.0-2.0.0-20120117.082939-16.pom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The POM file is invalid. The POM is a module's meta data file and should list the correct version. This is what is causing your problems.
Snapshots have a tendency to be unstable (not always a good idea to use them).

Options?

1. Use a different snapshot module version.
2. If you really need this particular jar then I'd advise downloading it directly as follows:

   https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/com/vaadin/addon/jpacontainer-addon-agpl-3.0/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/jpacontainer-addon-agpl-3.0-2.0.0-20120117.082939-16.jar

## Update

That module is plain broken :-(

The jar can be found when browsing the file storage as follows:

https://oss.sonatype.org/index.html#view-repositories;vaadin-snapshots~browsestorage~/com/vaadin/addon/jpacontainer-addon-agpl-3.0/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/jpacontainer-addon-agpl-3.0-2.0.0-20120117.082939-16.jar

This explains why the following dependency declaration in Maven might work:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.vaadin.addon</groupId>
  <artifactId>jpacontainer-addon-agpl-3.0</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Without a proper POM the Nexus index will not be updated properly

https://oss.sonatype.org/index.html#nexus-search;gav~~jpacontainer-addon-agpl-3.0~2.0.0-SNAPSHOT~~

As you can see the jar is missing... So jar is present, repository index is unreliable